# How to implement dual encoder LSTM in Keras?

Tags: keras, tf.keras

[image]

I want to implement this model in TensorFlow Keras API. I am confused about how to implement the sigmoid(C*M*R) function in Keras. How to merge the output of both LSTM's an compute the above function ? Can someone please help !

Comment: The image alone isn't helpful. You need to explain what each of those components in the image are

Comment: @thushv89 RNN here is an LSTM cell. C and R are sentences encoded into a fixed dimension by the two LSTM's. Then they are passed through a function sigmoid(CMR).
We can assume that R and C are both 256 dimensional matrices and M is a 256 * 256 matrix. The matrix M is learned during training.